# Exception while calling AsynJob

Tags: hibernate

Getting this exception while calling asynJob :

> org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [org.jbpm.graph.exe.Token#1391113]G

Comment: How we can reproduce this exception in hibernate using two transaction . Please share code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some code.